# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2x^k= \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$ for $0 < |x| < 1$

Tags: algorithms, summation

Show that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2x^k= \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$$ for $0 < |x| < 1$.

(This is appendix question A.1-3 from Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen)

Comment: Is this an exercise about generating functions or just normal summations?

Comment: Normal summations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2x^k= x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2x^{k-1}= x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^k$$

Can you follow on from this?

**Edit: some more detail:**

The idea with a question like this is to transform the question into something we already know. In this case, the sum looks remarkably similar to $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x} \text{ for } 0<x<1$$

Can you see a way to transform (perhaps by differentiating) the original sum into the simpler one above?

**Continuation (if you get stuck):**

$$x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^k = x\frac{d}{dx}\left(  x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}\right)= x\frac{d}{dx}\left(  x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k\right)= x\frac{d}{dx}\left(  x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Why did you derivate?

Comment: I've added some more detail. Does that help?

Comment: I have to find a way to get out the k?

Comment: This is correct?
(x^2)*sum(x^k) where k=0 to infinity

Comment: I've added a bit more... do you see why the differentiating helped now? And do you see how to finish?

Comment: Why x*sum(k^2)(x^(k-1)), k=0 to infinity is equal d/dx sum(k * (x^k)), k=0 to infinity. Is it a property?

Comment: $x\frac{d}{dx}kx^k = xk^2x^{k-1}=k^2x^k.$

Comment: The book has a formula ((A.8) in my edition) for pretty much all you need to finish from your hints: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k x^k = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$, and argues generally similar to you.  Maybe it's easier to communicate that way.

Answer (score 1):

To find the required sum you could just find the sum of the geometric progression $1,x,x^2,x^3,... \space where \space |x|\lt 1,$ and then double differentiate it .$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac 1{1-x}\\=>\frac d{dx}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\right)=\frac d{dx}\left(\frac 1{1-x}\right)\\=>\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1}=\frac 1{(1-x)^2}\\=>\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k=\frac x{(1-x)^2}\\=>\frac d{dx}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k\right)=\frac d{dx}\left(\frac x{(1-x)^2}\right)\\=>\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2x^{k-1}=\frac{(1-x)^2+2(1-x)x}{(1-x)^4}\\=>\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2x^{k-1}=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}\\=>\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2x^k=\frac {x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$$