# How to find the $~\text{Var}(X)~$ of the function $~f(x)=2(1/3)^x~$ where $~x=1,2,3,\cdots~$

Tags: probability-theory, variance

> How to find the $~\text{Var}(X)~$ of the function $~f(x)=2(1/3)^x~$ where $~x=1,2,3,\cdots~$?

I was able to find $~E[X]~$ by writing out the series and subtracting series to find that $~E[X] = 3/4~$, but I'm having trouble finding $~E[X^2]~$ through series notation.

So far I have $$E[X^2]=2[1^2(1/3)+2^2(1/3)^2+3^2(1/3)^3+...]~.$$ How do I sum this series to find $~E[X^2]~$ and thus the  $~\text{Var}(X)~$?

Thank you and I appreciate any help!

Comment: Idea is to differentiate under the summation to calculate $E[X(X-1)]$. From there you can calculate the variance. To be more precise: $x(x-1)p^x = p^2\cdot(p^x)''$.

Comment: How can $E[X]$ be $\frac{3}{4}$ when the least value of $X$ is $1$?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\E}{\Bbb{E}}$Note that your random variable has PMF $f(x) = q^{x-1}p$, where $p=2/3$ and $q=1/3$.

This means that $X$ has a **Geometric distribution** on $\Bbb{Z}^{+}$, so its variance is $\frac{q}{p^2} = \frac{1/3}{4/9} = \frac{3}{4}$, using the formula for the variance of a Geometric random variable.

---

If you want to sum your series directly to find $\E\left[X^2\right]$, note that $$\E\left[X^2\right] = \sum\limits _{k=1}^{\infty}k^2 q^{k-1}p = \frac{p}{q} \sum\limits _{k=1}^{\infty}k^2 q^{k}.$$

Now, it [is shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847415/show-that-sum-k-0-inftyk2xk-fracx1x1-x3-for-0-x-1) that $$\sum\limits _{k=1}^{\infty}k^2 z^k = \frac{z(1+z)}{(1-z)^3}$$ if $|z|<1$. Use this result to evaluate the above sum.